nginx docker-compose - why are my docker container always have 80/tcp port?
I set my docker-compose.yml like below:
version: "3.8"
# !!make sure to put default.conf into /nginx/conf.d/ before running the stack.
services:
    ng_proxy: 
        image: nginx:latest
        restart: always
        # local folder : container location
        volumes:
            - ~/ngx/public:/var/www/html
            - ~/ngx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        ports:
          - 8100:100

and my nginx conf.d/default.conf:
server {
        listen 100 default_server;
        listen [::]:100 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

the container can run, but always with 80/tcp:
fd5e54xxxxxx   nginx:latest  "/docker-entrypoint.…"  80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8100->100/tcp, :::8100->100/tcp  ngx_web-ng_proxy-1

I always got error 502 bad gateway, when i try to access the port (http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8100), I believe it is because I already have another service running at port 80.
How can I set to start up docker-compose.yml or nginx so that the 80/tcp WON'T be there?

It comes from an EXPOSE 80 line in the Nginx image Dockerfile.  You can't change or remove it, but it also has no practical impact.  I'd suggest changing the port 100 back to the standard HTTP port 80 everywhere in your configuration.

You will always see port 80 because 80 is exposed in the nginx dockerfile.
But your host does not map port 80 in the container, so this port 80 can only be operated inside your container and will not affect the service of port 80 of your host.
Ref：

https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/479f90adc64a726d76890b0604b5116b8d7fe7f5/Dockerfile-debian.template#L109


if it will not affect, how come i cannot access it? I test with my local host I can access it no problem, just not at the production server. and I check my port 8100 are already open.

try use
ports:
- 8100:80
, can you give nginx error.log or docker log?

I don't have error message at all, and from docker ps it appear healthy

If I have other container port already have 80, will that affect?

ok, I found out the cause. somehow the mount volume is not working if i set it in docker-compose.yml

If your container network is not a host, it will not affect each other.
8100:80 Because the front port is the host and the back port is the container.

you are right, and I figured out what happen. somehow the container did not use my default.conf file to do the setting. i change it to custom.conf, and minor folder change, then it works
